# Helper for check all params node.js - sails - express

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, express, sails.js

I want to check my params in my controllers.
For the moment, I'm doing like that:

```
create: function (req, res) {
    if(req.params.label && req.params.password){
     // do stuff
     }
}
```

But I want to do this more quickly.
I'm wondering if there is no tools which already exist.

I want to do things like that:

```
create: function (req, res) {
    checkParams({label: {empty: false}, password: {empty: false}}, function(err){
        // Do stuff
     });
}
```

Do you know something which could help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll answer to myself.

I found this module, really useful. https://github.com/chriso/node-validator

And I wrote, by my own (and with a little help from here =D) a little helper for manage validations:

http://pastebin.com/Bw0qdbu1

Thanks for the help ;)
Two samples are available in the file, I'm using sails.js. But it can be used with anything, you need the validator package, obviously.

```
npm install validator --save
```

Don't forget to import validator at the start of file.

```
var validator = require('../services/validator');
```