# Dynamic method call from string with args - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I want to write a little function which receive an array of objects which describe rule(s) to check, using node-validator.

I wrote this:

http://pastebin.com/gWarw98P

The error is at the line 68. I'm using the same example than describe in the method description. And I have to manage args dynamically too.

If I replace:

```
check(value, rule[j].message).rule[j]['function']();
```

By

```
check(value, rule[j].message).isNumeric();
```

It works. So my main problem is to call the good method...

Can you help me?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have done to write my code, validation module can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077325/helper-for-check-all-params-node-js-sails-express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the property of the object returned by `check()` based on the value of `rule[j]['function']`, you need to use bracket notation:

```
check(value, rule[j].message)[rule[j].function]();
```

Comment: Ohhhh, thank you! I tried with {} notation, because in PHP we can do that with variables... And I didn't thought to remove the dot before the bracket so... Okay, it works!
Do you know how can I generate my args depends on rule[j].args?

Comment: @Vadorequest: `func.apply(thisArg, args)` will call a function with the argument array `args` and a `this` of `thisArg`. So in this case, it would be `var validation = check(value, rule[j].message); validation[rule[j].function].apply(validation, rule[j].args);`.